# C# Task.Factory.StartNew Longrunning

Tags: c#, threadpool

I would like to find out why the following needs to be blocked in order to get the console to write:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("KO"), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

and this does not:

```
new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("KO")).Start();
```

According to C# 5.0 in a nutshell, `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is supposed to make the task NOT use pooled threads (which are background threads), meaning it should be using a foreground thread just like a regular thread, except with a regular thread, one does not need to `Console.Readline` or `Wait()` but with a `Task`, doesn't matter whether it's long running or not, I always have to block the main thread in some way.

So what good is `LongRunning` or `OnComplete()` or `GetAwaiter()` or `GetResult()` or any other function which is supposed to render a result If I always have to block the main thread myself to actually get the result?

Comment: *meaning it should be using a foreground thread* [No, it not should do that.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs,61)

Answer (score 3):

You're relying on undefined behaviour. Don't do that.

You don't need to wait for a task to have it work - it's just the only way to be sure that it actually completed in some way. I assume you're just using a console application with nothing but the code above - by the time the thread actually gets to the `Console.WriteLine` part, the main thread is dead, and with it all the background threads. `new Thread` creates a foreground thread by default, which prevents the application as a whole from exiting, despite the fact that the "main" thread was terminated.

The idea behind tasks (and any kind of asynchronous operations, really) is that they allow you to make concurrent requests, and build chains of asynchronous operations (making them behave synchronously, which you usually want). But you still need points of synchronization to actually make a workable application - if your application exits before the tasks are done, too bad :)

You can see this if you just do a `Console.ReadLine` instead of waiting for the task to finish explicitly - it still runs in the background, independently of the main thread of execution, but now you give it enough time to complete. In most applications, you do asynchronous operations *asynchronously* to the main thread - for example, a result of a button click might be an asynchronous HTTP request that doesn't block the UI, but if the UI is closed, the request is still terminated.

Comment: Hi Luaan, thanks for clearing that up. I just thought that "LongRunning" was supposed to shift the Task from a background thread onto a foreground thread and as you say prevent the application from exiting just as a normal thread would. But I understand what your saying about the application exiting before the Task, I'd never know the result so the best would be to explicitly block the threat until I get whatever result. I was also under the impression that a OnCompleted() was supposed to do that for me, so when it didnt I thought something was wrong.

Comment: @AndrewH It's just a hint to the task scheduler that it's not a pure CPU task - which usually means that it isn't assigned a thread from the thread pool. But the new thread is still a background thread - that's completely orthogonal to being a thread-pool thread. Any thread can be foreground or background - foreground threads block application exit, background threads don't. But ideally, you want to be clear about what your threads are doing and only exit the application when everything is done. Do you like apps that don't have a UI anymore but just won't die? This is a common cause :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Luaan! much appreciated.